# How to Solve Compiling "_OBJC_CLASS_$_xxxx", referenced from" Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image: Error]

I am facing an issue "_OBJC_CLASS_$_xxxx", referenced from" in Xcode project .I have done all tricks which is available Stackoverflow.Adding .m files to compile source but no luck.I am unable to pointout the issue . Kindly somebody please Help me regarding issue .I attach screenshot below ... Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you check all the files in your bundle, In there any file marked red color(if not available/deleted file from actual location but still existing in bundle).

Comment: is this camera,videogenerator, etc are any library files installed from pod?

Comment: Try In build setting- Set: Build Active Architecture to YES

Comment: @VarinderSingh: Also do enable bitcode "No" in build setting

Answer (score 1):

May be u have missed to import .m files in compile source .

Comment: Have u check the bundle  resource